# Get Full product link REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to get all product details via:

```
https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/:sku
```

but, I can't find a full product rewrite link, How to get that?

Comment: Not clear about `a full product rewrite link`? Can you explain more details? You mean the url will contain the base url?

Comment: I want to get the full product URL from above API or any API. is that possiple?

Comment: https://domain.com/product_url_key.html This is not working, It return 404 not found error.
Please help to solve this. Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137963)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full URL is not available as far as I'm aware, but the `url_key` is. So you could construct the product link from that, i.e:

`https://domain.com/product_url_key.html`

Comment: Where can I get {{product_url_key.html }} from the REST API in the above API?

Comment: `url_key` is stored under `custom_attributes` in the `response`.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work so well after reindex , feel a good way is using the real product id :

https://domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/{id number}

Comment: The question was asking about getting a product URL using the REST API, this doesn't really answer that.

Comment: Using the REST API to get product id first , then add it to https://domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/  , just like adding url_key to https://domain.com/product_url_key.html